# Best linux Distro for older machines? (Macbook end 2009)

Tags: mac, macbook, distro-recommendation

My parents have an old laptop ( [Macbook ref](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP579?locale=fr_FR&viewlocale=en_US) ) wich start to lag on the last OS version. So I'm looking for a light distro to install.

They only use the laptop to go on internet (any browser) and use Open Office or equivalent. But I need a very intuitive distro 'cause they don't very understand how a computer works and I'm too far away for any computer maintenance (I just can install the distro for Christmas).

I hesitate between Ubuntu with an other DE than Unity  (elementary OS?) or Linux Mint (lighter, but have a quite bad GUI) or buy the OS X Snow Leopard (past version of OSX).

Thanks for your help!

PS: I hope I have not made too many spelling mistakes... ^^'

Comment: I hate to say this, but if your parents really don't have much in the way of computer skills Mac OSX (a reinstall, given you have the disk), is probably the way to go- especially if they encounter issues while you're away. Then again, you could refer your parents to AskUbuntu :) Other than that, Elementary OS is probably a good call.

Comment: For AskUbuntu I think it won't be possible 'cause they are very bad in english (french cliché...) and are frightened at the sight of the terminal...
Anyway, I'll ask them if they have the disk, otherwise I'll install Elementary I think (I'll try it first to see if it's really intuitive or not).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best distro for old hardware is Lubuntu.
Elementary OS is the best looking distro. You can go for it too.

Comment: Sadly Elementary dropped support for 32 bit so it's not a great choice for a lot of older machines now.

Answer (score 1):

you should go for "xfce" linux distros . They are free and old- hardware friendly. They are the lightest versions ,are easy to use and don't lag on old hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Ubuntu derivates, then Lubuntu and Xubuntu should be ok for you.